# How to aggregate nested fields to include null values?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm having trouble aggregating my nested data to include null values as well.
I'm using Elasticsearch version 6.8

I'll simplify the problem, I've a nested field that looks like:

```
PUT test/doc/_mapping 
{
  "properties": {
    "fields": {
            "type" : "nested",
            "properties" : {
              "name" : {
                "type" : "keyword"
              },
              "value" : {
                "type" : "long"
              }
            }
    }
  }
}
```

I created 3 documents:

```
PUT test/doc/1
{
  "fields" : {
    "name" : "aaa",
    "value" : 1
  }
}

PUT test/doc/2
{
  "fields" : [{
    "name" : "aaa",
    "value" : 1
  },
  {
    "name" : "bbb",
    "value" : 2
  }]
}

PUT test/doc/3
{
  "fields" : [
  {
    "name" : "bbb",
    "value" : 2
  }]
}
```

Now I want to group my data to get how many documents there are where **name="bbb"** group by each **value**.

For the above data I want to get:

**2** – 2 documents

**N/A** – 1 document (the first document where bbb is missing)

The problem is with the null values, I cannot find a way to match the documents where "bbb" is null and put them in a N/A bucket.

So far I wrote a query that match the values where "bbb" exist:

```
GET test/doc/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "my_agg": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "fields"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "my_filter": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "fields.name": "bbb"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "my_term": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "fields.value"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the response is:

```
  "aggregations" : {
    "my_agg" : {
      "doc_count" : 4,
      "my_filter" : {
        "doc_count" : 2,
        "my_term" : {
          "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
          "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
          "buckets" : [
            {
              "key" : 2,
              "doc_count" : 2
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I want to get also:

```
"key" : 0 (for N/A)
"doc_count" : 1
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean with *I cannot find a way to match the documents where "bbb" is null and put them in a N/A bucket.*? As far as I can see from your sample data, you haven't index a document where the field name is null.

Comment: I'll try to clarify, for each document I want to aggregate my data in the following way:
1. If the nested document contains "name == bbb" then put this document in the bucket of the **value**.
For example: document with ID 3, contain "name == bbb", then aggregate it in the bucket "2" (name:"bbb", value:2)
2. If the nested document does not contain "name == bbb" then put this document in a separate bucket, for example bucket "0" which for me is equivalent to N/A.
For example: document with ID 1 does not contain "name == bbb" so I want to put it in bucket with key "0".

Comment: *...for example bucket "0" **which for me is equivalent to N/A.** In your specific use case this might be true but for **Elasticsearch** this is not.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you want to know the buckets where there was zero/null/no matches. You can use [min_doc_count](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_minimum_document_count_4)

```
GET test/doc/_search
{
  "size": ,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "my_agg": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "fields"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "my_filter": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "fields.name": "bbb"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "my_term": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "fields.value", --> you can also use "_id" to get count based on each document
                "min_doc_count": 0  --> this will include all the buckets where count is zero/ or there is no match.
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You could also use [inner_hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#nested-inner-hits) to find a hit in each document or use `_id` in above aggregations query.

```
POST test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_all": {}
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "fields",
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "fields.name": "bbb"
              }
            },
            "inner_hits": {}
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Polynomial Proton, but this is not exactly what I wanted.
Please see my clarification above, if the nested field contains "name == bbb", then put it in the value bucket (name: bbb, value: 55 -> the bucket should be 55).
This part you did it right :)
But if the nested document doesn’t contain "name == bbb" put these documents in the **same** default bucket, for example bucket "0" which for me is equivalent to N/A